# Please help me with scam?

Tags: banking, scams, sugar-daddy

I stupidly found a sugar daddy site and found one. He sent me $1900 and now wants it back and is threatening to call the police if I don’t send it back. I do not have the money in my account since it was an e-check and my bank has to process and authorize it first. I honestly don’t really wanna go to jail. What do i do?

Comment: Commenting to show agreement with the answer below - (1) DO NOT CONTACT THE SCAMMER AGAIN - since you have almost fallen to a scam already, be incredibly vigilant about future possible scams - this person and their associates will continue to contact you, pretending to be other people, to scam you again. (2) Contact the bank to tell them about the likely fraud - it will eventually be discovered that the payment received was no good and they will pull the funds from your account either way. better for you to go to them first as a sign of good faith that you were not intentionally participating.

Comment: Yeah, a criminal isn't going to call the police on you. I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 18):

Don't send any money back to him.  This is a complete scam.

He will not be contacting the police; he is a scam artist.  Simply stop all communications with him.

Your next step should be to contact the bank and let them know that you found out that the e-check you deposited is likely bad.  If and when the bank does process and authorize it, do not spend the money, because the bank will eventually need to take this money back out of your account.

If you do attempt to send money to this scammer, you will lose this money.

Finally, my recommendation to you is to not attempt to do the "sugar daddy" thing again.  It is all scams.

Comment: If you really want to hear this scammer change his tune tell him that you have already contacted the police. But seriously it's better not to talk to him at all.